# Laravel Google Analytics API - fetching all dates(including those with missing values)

Tags: php, google-analytics

I have a method that fetches sessions/pageviews for the past 30 days :

```
public function getReport($analytics,$viewId){

    // Create the DateRange object.
    $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
    $dateRange->setStartDate("30daysAgo");
    $dateRange->setEndDate("yesterday");

    // Create the Metrics object.
    $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
    $sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
    $sessions->setAlias("sessions");

    $pageviews = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
    $pageviews->setExpression("ga:pageviews");
    $pageviews->setAlias("pageviews");

    $dates = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
    $dates->setName("ga:date");

    // Create the ReportRequest object.
    $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
    $request->setViewId($viewId);
    $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
    $request->setMetrics(array($sessions, $pageviews));
    $request->setDimensions(array($dates));

    $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
    $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
    return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );

}
```

The problem is that it will return the dimension ga:date value only if I have some pageviews/sessions on that date, otherwise it will skip it.
Is there a way to force it to return all dates for the past 30 days even those with no sessions/pageviews?